# Porting Xamarin.android app to xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have an application developed in Xmarin.android. As app development is fully completed now I would like to start developing xamarin.ios. What is the right method to do so without rewriting much code?

Comment: there is no way to answer this.  It depends on your code, your app design and architecture, etc.  There is no "right" answer

Answer (score 0):

IOS and Android have there own UI concepts and components.

In your case the will need UI aspects in Xamarin.IOS. However, the Business logic, server communication, parsers etc can be shared between the two platforms. the sharing can be achieved by using Portable Class Libraries.

More details of PCL can be obtained from this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=macos

Comment: It's more common to put shared logic in a [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/net-standard?tabs=windows) project these days. Shared Projects or Portable Class Libraries are not the way to go in 2018.